# DQL and multiple WHERE statements

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I want to write query with multiple `WHERE` statements.

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('s');

    $query->select('s.id,s.internalId as internal_id,s.firstName as first_name,s.lastName as last_name,st.name as store_name,sts.name as status_name')
        ->leftJoin('s.store', 'st')
       ->leftJoin('s.studentStatus', 'sts')
        ->where($query->expr()->orx(
            //$query->expr()->eq('s.store_id', ':location'),
            $query->expr()->like('s.internalId', ':internalId'),
            $query->expr()->like($query->expr()->concat($query->expr()->literal(' '), 'lower(s.firstName)'), ':name'),
            $query->expr()->like($query->expr()->concat($query->expr()->literal(' '), 'lower(s.lastName)'), ':name'),
            $query->expr()->like($query->expr()->concat($query->expr()->concat($query->expr()->literal(' '), 'lower(s.firstName)'), $query->expr()->concat($query->expr()->literal(' '), 'lower(s.lastName)')), ':name'),
            $query->expr()->like($query->expr()->concat($query->expr()->concat($query->expr()->literal(' '), 'lower(s.lastName)'), $query->expr()->concat($query->expr()->literal(' '), 'lower(s.firstName)')), ':name')
        ))
        ->setParameter('name', "%{$term}%")
        ->setParameter('internalId', "%{$internalId}")
        //->setParameter('location', "{$location}")
        ->orderBy('s.lastName', 'ASC')
        ->setMaxResults((int) $limit);
```

Commented line in the above query is not working.

Comment: What do you mean be mutliple "where"? Maybe you mean "andWhere" ?

Comment: Yes! andWhere also not working. i want to check the value is equal to column value what's wrong in my Query . ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DoctrineQueryBuilder (DQL) has those [helper methods](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#high-level-api-methods):

```
->where($where)
->andWhere($where)
->orWhere($where)
```

also DQL allows to build [expressions](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#the-expr-class):

```
$qb->add('select', new Expr\Select(array('u')))
   ->add('from', new Expr\From('User', 'u'))
   ->add('where', $qb->expr()->orX(
       $qb->expr()->eq('u.id', '?1'),
       $qb->expr()->like('u.nickname', '?2')
   ))
   ->add('orderBy', new Expr\OrderBy('u.name', 'ASC'));
```

Using `where` clear all previous `where` statements.

Using `orWhere` place `OR` for next statements.

Using `andWhere` place `AND` for next statements.

You should build query like that:

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('s')
    ->select('s.id,s.internalId as internal_id,s.firstName as first_name,s.lastName as last_name,st.name as store_name,sts.name as status_name')
    ->leftJoin('s.studentStatus', 'sts')
    ->leftJoin('s.store', 'st')
    ->where('s.store_id = :location') // not working
    ->andWhere('lower(s.firstName) LIKE :name')
    ->orWhere('lower(s.lastName) LIKE :name')
    ->orWhere('s.internalId LIKE :internalId')
    ->setParameter('name', "%{$term}%")
    ->setParameter('internalId', "%{$term}%")
    ->setParameter('location', $location)
    ->orderBy('s.lastName', 'ASC')
    ->setMaxResults((int) $limit)
    ->getQuery();
```

Comment: Thanks for Suggestion, i changed my Query in your syntax structure. except location its working fine, but with location its not working. column exist in the same table.